# Status bar text color changing

Tags: ios, webview

So I have an app which mainly consists of web views. Everyhting is working fine, I have my status bar and navigation bars configured as I like.

The only issue is, when I go to a website that has a "Choose File" option, it opens the Saved Images to select a image (no issue here), then when I tap on the saved images table cell, the status bar text goes from white to black and I am unable to revert back.

I have tried calling `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` in `viewDidAppear`, `viewDidDisappear`, etc which solves it reverting, but only on that single view it changes.

Any ideas on how to keep it `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` all the time? I should note I have `[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];` declared in the App Delegate, and `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` set to `NO`.

Thanks.

UPDATE with screenshots:
[image: Displaying properly.][image: Not displaying properly.]

UPDATE 7/14

I managed to get it somewhat working, but in turn it broke the default video player status bar text. Plus it just won't hide to begin with.

I used:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}

-(void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.webView stopLoading];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
}
```

FINAL UPDATE??

Not pretty, but i managed to somewhat get the effect all together between the video player and image uploader.

```
-(void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.webView stopLoading];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES
                                            withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set "View controller-based status bar appearance” to NO in your info.list file;

Add this code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

to -application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: of the AppDelegate.m.

I hope your problem will be solved

Comment: As stated, I have already done this. Post updated with screenshots for a visual example.